# fullcalendar.js: times not showing up in agenda view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Like others I'm having problems getting timed events to show up on the agendaWeek view. If you look at the events below, the first two are mine and show up as all day events. The last one is from the documentation and shows up in the correct time block. I've been staring at this so long I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Can anyone else see it?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            month:0,//current year assumed, first day of month assumed
            date: 4,
            height: 650,
            header: {left: 'title',center:'agendaWeek'},
            events: [

                        {
                          title : 'Fred',
                          start : '2010-01-04 08:00:00',
                          end   : '2010-01-04 09:00:00',
                          allday : false
                        },
                        {
                          title : 'Betty',
                          start : '2010-01-06 08:00:00',
                          allday : false
                        },

                        {
                            title  : 'event3',
                            start  : '2010-01-05 12:30:00',
                            allDay : false // will make the time show
                        }


                    ]       

                });

                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem as follows: Where you have `allday` you need **`allDay`** with a capital `D`.

Cheers!